# Lower bound for logarithmic Sobolev constant for compact manifold by negative Ricci lower bound

Tags: differential-geometry, riemannian-geometry

I just study a paper by Saloff-Coste

http://matwbn.icm.edu.pl/ksiazki/cm/cm67/cm67111.pdf

On page 118 there is theorem 9

[image: theorem 9]

And on page 119 in remark 3, there is an inequality

[image: remark]

The whole thing that I want to know is about $C(n, k, \epsilon)$.

$C$ is a constant that depends to dimension $n$. But what order of $n$?
If $C=O(n^x)$ where $x>0$ (i.e. $C$ tends to infinity as $n$ grows up) my problem will be solved.

I will be very grateful if I have your point of view in this case.
Thanks

Comment: The way the theorem is stated it makes no claim about any growth bounds for C depending on n. It could be polynomial in n but it could also grow much faster. Maybe one can go through the proof carefully and see whether a strengthening of the statement with an explicit function of n is possible.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. I know c and C depend on dimension n. But I would like to know are they growing up when n grows up or not? Are c and n directly related? or they can be inversely related!!